# Запрос на выборку SQL

Tags: mysql

Всем привет! Есть следующая задача: "Получить дату максимальных продаж, если таких дат несколько, то самую раннюю из них". Я понимаю, как собрать данные по датам:

```
 select date, sum(total) from sale group by date;
```

получаю:

```
 mysql> select date, sum(total) from sale group by date;
 +------------+------------+
 | date       | sum(total) |
 +------------+------------+
 | 2017-01-01 |     920.00 |
 | 2017-01-02 |    1105.00 |
 | 2017-01-03 |     500.00 |
 | 2017-01-05 |     820.00 |
 +------------+------------+
 4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Натолкните на мысль, как решить. Не пойму как решать дальше.

Comment: А каков Ваш вопрос?

Comment: where date = (select min(date) from sale)

Comment: добавить к этому `order by sum(total) desc, date limit 1`

Comment: @Mike, а если максимальное количество продаж будет одинаково в двух разных датах?

Comment: В сортировке дата стоит, так что первой записью окажется как раз с минимальной датой

Answer (score -1):

Решил это с помощью having sum(total) вместо select date, sum(total)

Comment: Привидите пожалуйста полный запрос и его вывод.